# IntelliJ txt file doesn't get included when building jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to build my project to a jar file. When I first opened the jar file I noticed nothing happened. I then launched the jar file from cmd. Then I saw it throws an error because it cannot find a txt file. This is the error:

[image]

Executing the program in IntelliJ works fine so I am assuming the txt file is not included in the artifact. This is how I use the txt file in the code:

[image]

This is what my file structure looks like:

[image]

This is what my artifact settings look like:

[image]

I tried putting the txt file in the src folder and manually including it in the artifact settings, I tried putting the txt file in the resources folder (It is marked as Resources Root) and I tried using the resources folder and also manually adding the resources folder to the artifact settings (this is the last thing I tried and is visible in the picture of my artifact settings).

I am really confused why the txt file doesn't seem to be in the jar file. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the file in the `resources` folder, and instead of `File` try using `getResourceAsStream` to get the contents of the file:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt");
Scanner pathScanner = new Scanner(in);
```

Comment: Thank you this works! However I forgot to mention that in another part of the code I also use the data.txt file but here I don't read it but write to it like this:
File pathFile = new File("resources/data.txt");
FileWriter pathWriter = new FileWriter(pathFile);
How can I make this work with the InputStream?

Comment: So you asked the wrong question. It should be "I can't read a txt file from a jar" instead of "The file is not included.". You know a jar file is just a zip file that you can open and check?

Comment: @SurfMan I asked the wrong question because I had no idea what was going on. I know a bit of basic java and tried to compile it to a jar file. In the meantime I found out you can't change jar files so you will have to store data somewhere else.

Comment: @BorekBandell you can try injecting a file into the jar like this: `<jar-path>.jar -C resources data.txt`. Not sure if this can fit your use-case, but it is used in cases, say you have a config file on the server, and you need your jar to use those values from there

Comment: For your question, to write to a file you would need not this `InputStream` but an `OutputStream`. Also, make sure you close these streams once finished. @BorekBandell

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `?*.txt` as resource pattern in the compiler options.

[image]

Comment: For me it did not contain .txt so I added it. Then I tried running the jar file but now I get a no main manifest attribute error even though I did select a main class.
Edit: nevermind I tried creating the artifact again and now this error is gone. I still see the original error.